# Date counter - remaining X days

Tags: google-apps-script

Please, inform if it's possible to insert on a page at google drive/doc something that can counts days until some date.
Example:

00 months and 00 days left.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code bellow. 
Edit the variable called targetDate with the end date.

```
function doGet() {
   var today = new Date();
  var targetDate = new Date(2014, 1, 25) // - February 25th of 2014 
  today.setHours(0,0,0,0);

  var ui = UiApp.createApplication();
  ui.add(ui.createLabel(calcDate(today, targetDate)));
   return ui;
}


function calcDate(date1,date2) {
    var diff = Math.floor(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    var day = 1000* 60 * 60 * 24;

    var days = Math.floor(diff/day);
    var months = Math.floor(days/31);
    var years = Math.floor(months/12);

    var message = days + " days " ;
    message += months + " months ";
    message += years + " years left \n";

    return message
}
```

Live version can be found [here](https://script.google.com/macros/d/11sVj9t7rrNoegLmpXNKXY2rXyD-StofOqFFvTQ6Fo58t9xBYGj4Ft4Z5/edit?template=default&folder=0B0kQD4hSd4KASUJKb2cya0NET1U&usp=drive_web).

Comment: This code is a start. Can be improved for a gdoc if you embed it on a sidebar and display a live countdown. For that you need to use htmlService (to use setInterval) and not uiservice like ifs done here.

Answer (score 0):

Just something to note; I blindly changed the number making up targetDate, but be careful, months count from 0 not 1. 0 is Jan, 1 is Feb, etc.